# About best way to perfom checksum

Tags: communication, digital-communications, signal-integrity, telecommunications, data-acquisition

From my knowledge,checksum can be done using Xor or adding the bytes of the frame...i have to create a communication between ATmega32 microcontroller and matlab to perform some functions...which is the best  for data integrity..Xor or adding the data frame?

Comment: Define best, and for what? How much data? If you need cryptographic hash then use it. If CRC is enough, use it. Summing and xoring checksums can be good enough too.

Comment: Communication with PC and ATMega32? Over what interface? Ethernet, radio link, infrared, USB? How much data and what size packets?

Comment: Uart rs232..data size :8 bits

Comment: I want to assure data integrity...what is received is exactly what is sent

Comment: The data to be sent to PC is 8 bits?

Comment: Uart sends 8 bits at a time,so if the data frame is more than 8 bits,the frame can be sent 8 bits by 8 bits

Comment: Yes, data is transmitted one byte at a time. But I asked how much data you have to send to know the packet size in bytes. 1 byte, 10, 100, 1000?

Comment: Frame size is 40 bytes

Comment: Will you be using assembly or C on the AVR? Is compiler avr-gcc with avr-libc?

Comment: C language...Atmel studio

Comment: Atmel studio is not a compiler, it is an IDE. If it uses avr-gcc and avr-libc then those provide you functions to calculate a CRC16 value that should be enough to protect 40-byte data packets easily.

Comment: So,i have to create the checksum function by myself...so i have to add or Xor all the frame bytes on both sender and receiver sides....so i ask..which is the better: adding the data or Xor them?

Comment: Whether you use XOR or adding makes no difference - the result will be a checksum either way. Checksums work for detecting some errors, but certainly not all. CRCs work better than checksums, but are more complicated to calculate. You needs to decide whether a fast & easy but less reliable checksum or a slower more complicated but more reliable CRC is appropriate for your application. There is no universal 'best' - it depends on your requirements.

Comment: Ok ..thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

Consider your BER requirements and all sources of errors.  For Ethernet UDP is less reliable since there is no feedback after all  CRC checks but TCP uses retry for error free. Similar with older comm channels  like ADLC/SDLC with ACK/NAK.

But for basic single bit error checking use odd parity and check UART for framing, parity,overrun errors. It may have a 16 byte buffer to prevent some overrun situations. Yet double bit or even bit errors are not detectable with single parity bit.

I had this problem from arc welders on a high speed channel over coax so I chose a 4bit  Hamming code (with an XOR tree) to create more data bits of redundancy and detect more bit errors per burst and added to a synchronous channel.

You could use CRC or some other method of ease of implementation or have a message counter for self checking remote Rx and request or. Compute message error rate or do a channel BER test during idle when something flagged seems incorrect. Lightning storms can be another source of bit errors for example and might not be avoidable.  So decide. How important, redundant or reliable are your messages.  Some may simply send twice to improve reliability or use an ACK NAK reply. For confirmation. It all depends on the channel specs and your needs.

For higher communication integrity HDD’s use long ECC bytes with >=11 bit/ packet error detect and correction with block error codes. This process is entirely hidden from the User and the OS and SMART may detect and is the reason why HDD’s are so reliable today yet without warning fail, Whereas in the old days 35 yrs ago, Soft error rates of 1e-10 and hard error rates of  1e-12 were acceptable and gave more warning of impending death of HDD or need to relocate sectors.

So choice of error detect or error correct depends on the BER, likelihood of disturbances, SNR, importance of data and thus choice of solution for acceptable error free rates.